# Crazy Distortion when Subdividing with Multires

Tags: modifiers, multiresolution

I want to sculpt with a texture brush so I'm using Multires to add detail to my mesh, but after three subdivides this happens:
[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit Mode > Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside/Inside*.

And check for overlapping vertex

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues with multires modifier.

First thing to troubleshoot this is find where the spikes originates.

Check if you have non-manifold faces (`Edit Mode > Select > None`, then `Viewport Menu > Select > Select All By Trait > Non Manifold`) and fix those selection areas if any.

Find and correct any overlapping faces, faces with very long edges and very short edges or some convex edges.

Still I had spikes when going to higher multires levels! Trying to smooth in higher levels resulted in worsening the spikes in other levels!!! I found only one way that properly solved the spike issue.

### The solution:

Duplicate your mesh with multi-resolution modifier.

Hide the original mesh with multires.

Apply the highest subdiv resolution on duplicated mesh.

Sculpt and smooth the spikes to get a clean high-res topology.

Unhide original mesh and set it to highest subdiv level if not already so that the vertex count matches the duplicated mesh.

Select the fixed duplicate mesh first and `[Ctrl]`select mesh with multi-resolution as second.

Go to `Modifiers panel > Multires > Shape > Reshape`. It might take a few seconds depending on PC spec and the mesh vertex count.

[image: Multires Reshape to fix spikes]

Once Reshape is done, you can hide/remove the duplicated mesh. It should have removed the spikes in all resolution levels.